# How to use Maven to compile and copy base project to several projects?

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, war, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a base project that is the main dependency of all my common projects. All projects work with Maven. And I'm using Eclipse. Right now the base project has a war and a jar execution. I use the jar in my common projects as a system dependency like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>base</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/myapproot/WEB-INF/lib/base.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

If I do some changes in the base, I need 3 steps:

1. build the base
2. copy the jar file
3. build the common project afterwards

There must be a better solution!

Is it possible to use either a maven or an ant file that do all three steps at once?

Comment: If you already build it with Maven are you using it via a system scope dependency? Can please show the pom file of the my.group Artfact? If you have done a `mvn install` on the my.group:base project there is no need to have a system scope dependency. Apart from that what are you using it from a WEB-INF/lib directory ?

Comment: I don't think that the hole pom is really interesting here and it's to long for a comment ;)
I use the war file for an observation and testing plattform and I ignore some of the classes in my jar that are not needed for the common projects.

Comment: If you ignore some classes than the resulting jar is simply wrong which means you should package it different (or better make a separate module).. without the pom at all it's hard to guess what's going wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Your common project is depending on the base project's artifact with scope `system` and using a `systemPath`.

Dependencies with `system` scope are not resolved from a Maven repository so your common project will always look for `my.group:base` here `${basedir}/myapproot/WEB-INF/lib/base.jar`.

This explains why you have to manually copy the base project's artifact.

If you remove ...

```
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${basedir}/myapproot/WEB-INF/lib/base.jar</systemPath>
```

... then your common project will resolve `my.group:base` from your Maven repository. Then, running `mvn install` on the base project will install `my.group:base` into your Maven repo and your common project will resolve it from there.

You will still have to build both base and common (this makes sense; you changed something and building is the way in which this *something* is made manifest) but you won't have to manually copy base's artifact.

Comment: That was my first attempt but because of reasons I can't recap right now I use the system dependency. Is there any way to force the compiling of the base dependency? Or an option in Eclipse to auto-call maven after editing?